# What table holds the information for the main image in Magento

Tags: mysql, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.8

Which database table holds the information on what image is supposed to be the **main** image of a product in Magento?

I looked at

- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
- and catalog_product_entity_varchar

But don't see how one image is flagged as the main (Base) image.

Magento version: 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information are stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.

Before you get this information from database you must know `attribute_id` for base image attribute, you can get this id by:

```
SELECT `attribute_id` FROM eav_attribute where `attribute_code` ='image' AND entity_type_id = 4;
```

For me result is `85`, now if we want get base image information for product with id 1020:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar where `attribute_id`=85 and `entity_id`=1020
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, mine is also 85.

Comment: Yeach, but not always :) it depend on installed modules and Magento version ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you open catalog_product_entity_vachar 
you will find an attribute id 
now search for table eav_attribute 
now search for that attribute id and you will find the image labels

Answer (score -1):

A little extra help: To display all image attributes with their codes, use:

`SELECT`attribute_id`,`attribute_code`FROM eav_attribute where`attribute_code`like '%image%' AND entity_type_id = 4;`

Comment: While this might be useful, this does not answer the OP's question. Wait until you have enough reputation, then you can post this as a comment.